# Como plotar um gráfico de série de tempo com ggridges?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico de casos por estado com `geom_density_ridges` do pacote `ggridges`, para ficar dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao plotar o gráfico, está ficando dessa forma, todos com a mesma linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado? Código que estou usando:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
library(openxlsx)
library(lubridate)

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                       "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
    httr::content() %>%
    '[['("results") %>%
    '[['(1) %>%
    '[['("arquivo") %>%
    '[['("url")

ms <- read.xlsx(url) %>%
    filter(is.na(municipio))

ms$data <- as_date(ms$data)

for(i in 9:14) {
    ms[,i] <- as.numeric(ms[,i])
}

rm(url, i)

ms %>%
    filter(data >= "2020-03-15", !is.na(estado)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data, y = estado, heigth = casosNovos)) +
    geom_density_ridges(fill = "lightblue")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiquei algumas situações para para o plot e falta de coerência para o `df`.

Achei interessante ajustar as data para poder checar se a organização do `df` realmente retratava a realidade. E ao proceder com as modificações percebi que os dados estavam organizados para o ano de 2090 e o seu `filter` não fazia sentido para datas.

Ajustando isto e criando uma nova variável para as regiões do país, de acordo ao plot indicado como referência, prossegui com o a criação do plot de densidade, porém acredito que o plot referência seja de linha ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebndG.jpg)/[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEG9T.jpg)), em função do nível de detalhe (mudanças abruptas para os valores de eixo y).

Nesta parte `ggridges` tive que declarar, novamente, `estado` como `factor` e troquei `geom_density_ridges` por `stat_density_ridges`. Informações sobre o quantil, `lab`, `fill` e `alpha` são referentes a estética visual do gráfico.

> Code de ajuste do `df`.

```
df <- ms %>%
  dplyr::mutate(data = format(as.Date(data), "%Y-%m-%d"))

d <- lubridate::years(as.numeric(max(year(df$data))) -
                   as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")))

df2 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(data = lubridate::parse_date_time(data, "%Y-%m-%d") - d,
                estado = as.factor(estado),
                regiao = ifelse(estado %in% c("BA", "SE", "AL", "PE",
                                              "PB", "RN", "CE", "PI", "MA"),
                                "NE", 
                                ifelse(estado %in% c("RS", "PR", "SC"), "S",
                                       ifelse(estado %in% c("SP", "RJ", "MG", 
                                                            "ES"), "SE",
                                              ifelse(estado %in% c("MS",
                                                                   "MT", "DF",
                                                                   "GO"), "CO",
                                                            "N"))))) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(data >= "2020-03-15", !is.na(estado), casosNovos > 0)
```

> Code para o plot.

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = data, heigth = casosNovos, y = as.factor(estado))) +
  stat_density_ridges(aes(fill = regiao),
                      quantile_lines = TRUE, 
                      quantiles = 2, alpha = 0.6) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#004C99", "#0066CC", "#0080FF",
                               "#00FFFF", "#33FF99")) +
  ylab("Estado") + xlab("") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente, tem como eu destacar a moda em vez da mediana nos gráficos e adicionar um ```trim = TRUE``` para cortar os dados no último dado disponível?

Comment: De nada! Acredito que sim, mas acho que dará um bom trabalho, verifique este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713272/adding-a-mean-to-geom-density-ridges). Quanto ao `trim`, veja este outro [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906240/stop-geom-density-ridges-from-showing-non-existent-tail-values/50011428#50011428).

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas!